# How far back can I retrieve time entries for using the end point GET /workspaces/{workspaceId}/user/{userId}/time-entries?

Tags: clockify

Using the end point 
GET /workspaces/{workspaceId}/user/{userId}/time-entries

I'm only able to retrieve time entries for a user going back about 14 days.

Am I able to retrieve older entries through the API?

I have tried the API using no start time, and using a start time 30 days ago and there are no results older than 2019-08-16T19:00:00Z (today is 2019-08-28)

I also tried emailing support@clockify.me and they told me to create an issue here.

I expected to be able to retrieve more than the last two weeks worth of entries.

Answer (score 0):

Jovana from Clockify Support got back to me and the issue was default page size was too small.  I added the parameter pageSize=10000 to allow me to retrieve more than a few days worth of entries.

Example

https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/{0}/user/{1}/time-entries?page-size=10000